# How to Checked and Unchecked Checked-box item of a List-box?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, listbox

Am Using the checkbox in listbox items, how to Checked and Unchecked all checkboxes from the listbox?

```
<ListBox Height="168" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="45,90,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding Ck, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

DataBinding is :

```
        List<uu> xx = new List<uu>();
        xx.Add(new uu { Name = "A", Ck = false });
        xx.Add(new uu { Name = "A", Ck = false });
        listBox1.ItemsSource = xx;
```

Update :

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
 foreach (ListBoxItem item in listBox1.Items)
        {
            CheckBox ch = (CheckBox)item;
            ch.IsChecked = true;
        }
```

Comment: *Setting* the ItemsSource is not exactly a data binding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of things to consider.

1) First use an ObservableCollection (preferred) or a BindingList instead of a List as your datasource

2) Make sure you implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your  class.  See an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx)

3) Now that you have your binding setup correctly, loop through the collection and set the checked property to false using a foreach or other loop.  The binding system will handle the rest and the changes in your list will be properly reflected on the UI

**UPDATE:**  Added a brief code example

In your code-behind:

```
    ObservableCollection<uu> list = new ObservableCollection<uu>();        

    MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Set the listbox's ItemsSource to your new ObservableCollection
        ListBox.ItemsSource = list;
    }

    public void SetAllFalse()
    {
        foreach (uu item in this.list)
        {
            item.Ck = false;
        }
    }
```

Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in uu class:

```
public class uu: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _ck;

    public bool Ck
    {
        get { return _ck; }
        set
        {
            _ck = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Ck");
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: robo has it right. It looks like you've set data binding up correctly but it's important to make sure your item implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. Otherwise you can set the property in code but it won't be reflected on the UI. ObservableCollection<T> is important for making sure the ListBox knows when an item is added or removed from the collection but it shouldn't impact whether or not the checkbox changes.

Comment: +1 Yes, this answer is more comprehensive than mine.  These are the key elements in XAML binding that should absolutely be understood when doing things like this.

Answer (score 1):

You would typically just use databindings as demonstrated below.

```
List<uu> items = listbox1.ItemsSource as List<uu>();

foreach (var item in items)
   item.Ck = true;
```

I am inferring the `Ck` variable name from your databindings and the ItemsSource type from your sample code.

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this foreach          (ListBoxItem item in listBox1.Items)
            {
                CheckBox ch = (CheckBox)item;
                ch.IsChecked = true;
            }

Comment: @Vero009: You cannot do that and you do not even *really* want to do that.

Comment: @Vero009: if you implement INotifyPropertyChanged you do not need to do that.  Changing the value on the uu class object will be automatically reflected in the UI through the binding which you have already set up.  No need to try and access the control directly